# Handling API route exceptions with java and spark

Tags: java, spark-framework

I have an API with routes for POST, PATCH, GET and DELETE. And I've had to create try catch blocks in each of these in order to catch a variety of possible errors. I currently make a call to an error class

`StandardError standardError = new StandardError("415");`

```
package domainObjects;

import com.google.gson.annotations.Expose;

public class StandardError {

    @Expose
    String status;

    @Expose
    String source;

    @Expose
    String detail;

    public StandardError(String errorCode){
        switch(errorCode) {

        case "409":
            this.status = "409";
            this.source = "/suppliers/";
            this.detail = "Resource already exists";
            break;
        case "500":
            this.status = "500";
            this.source = "/suppliers/";
            this.detail = "Unknown Error";
            break;
        case "415":
            this.status = "415";
            this.source = "/suppliers/";
            this.detail = "Unsupported media type. Content Type: application/vnd.api+json required.";
            break;
        case "404":
            this.status = "404";
            this.source = "/suppliers/";
            this.detail = "Resource does not exist";
            break;

        }
    }
```

The problem is that there's a large amount of replication in each of the route methods.

The [Exception Mapping](http://sparkjava.com/documentation.html#error-handling) section on spark describes the following route to catch exceptions. The issue being that this is only catching *one* particular exception, and I need to catch many.

Do I need to create a new exception route for each exception, or can I handle all the errors with `get("/throwexception", (request, response) -> {`?

```
get("/throwexception", (request, response) -> {
    throw new YourCustomException();
});

exception(YourCustomException.class, (exception, request, response) -> {
    // Handle the exception here
});
```